# Where did the outline of the hollowgast come from?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

In the movie for "Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children", for the scene where Miss Peregrine shoots the hollowgast at the cliff side, there is already an outline of where the hollowgast's body will fall.  If this is inside the time loop, where did the outline come from?  Would it not just disappear the next reset since the hollowgast had not yet died?  In other words, how did they know its exact resting position and who put it there, before the actual event happened?

Comment: maybe Abe put it there

Comment: @user35971 That would only make sense if he was able to travel to a time just before the loop with detailed knowledge of its exact placement and to time that would not have been disturbed by normal people in the normal timeline so the it would be there on that particular morning.  Otherwise it would be reset (see comments below).  I don't think there is an in-universe answer, just a movie trick that they thought would be "cool".

Answer (score 3):

The time loop is not absolutely fixed.  You could make the same argument for the catching of the falling squirrel.

It is mentioned elsewhere in the film that villagers visit the home and Miss Peregrine only kills them if she has to. Also, Abe can call into the loop to report on his searches in the outside world.  So, events can change in the loop from 'day' to 'day' as the loop re-runs.

We must assume that the outline was drawn after the first time the hollow appeared.

Comment: But doesn't everything inside the loop reset, except for the peculiars?  So are you saying that someone's "chore" is to redraw the outline exactly each day, just like it's someone's "chore" to stand under the tree to catch the falling squirrel?

Comment: @BlueGI I suspect not.  Once the outline is there, it probably remains across resets.  It one of those cinematic tricks left open to the viewer's interpretation.  An explanation to the viewer of the presence of a loop.

Comment: I was hoping there would be more to it than a "cinematic trick", because then that just seems like lazy story telling.  The next question would be then if that's possible, then why not keep the hollowgast dead for each loop?  Why do they have repeated tasks each day?  I realize there may be no answer, but it bugs me...